# NSWindow prevent window ordering when clicking on title bar

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, titlebar

`[NSApp preventWindowOrdering]` is good for `NSView` with `shouldDelayWindowOrderingForEvent` and `acceptsFirstMouse`. Have anybody implemented same feature for `NSWindow's` titlebar??

Comment: What is your question? Why to implement that for titlebar?

Comment: My app runs in "always on top" mode. If it is above fullscreen application (like PowerPoint) when I click on my app's title bar PowerPoint exits fullscreen mode. I need to prevent that exiting.

Comment: Ok, I found solution that worked for me. Just use NSPanel with NSNonactivatingPanelMask.